# Eclipse launch files ignored by git

Tags: eclipse, git

I save locally my launch files per project in Eclipse (*.launch).

I wanted to commit them, but couldn't see the in the commit list in SourceTree. Also in Eclipse it is shown the files are ignored.

In the .gitignore file I only have the target folder defined.

How is it possible these files are ignored? Are there default file extensions that are ignored in Eclipse? I couldn't find any information on this type of ignore :(

The launch file is in the same project root as the pom file.

Launch configuration:

[image]

Navigator view:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps Eclipse has other mechanisms for ignoring files. Look through the settings to see if you can find anything relevant.

Comment: Good hint! But nothing there too :(

Comment: Could you please show the _Common_ tab of your launch configuration and the `*.launch` file in the _Navigator_ view?

Comment: Done ;) @howlger

Comment: @FabiYo Thx. For the shown launch configuration the location is missing. All others are probably listed in the `.gitignore` file of the (project) folder or of the parent/ancestor folder: in the _Git Repositories_ view under the _Working Tree_ node look if there is a `.gitignore` file for all projects (e. g. in the root folder of the Git repository).

Comment: @howlger strange, I must have removed it by accident the location. Anyway the location is /web in this example and it works fine :) In the Working Tree there is no global .gitignore. Only per project, but only target folder in there. Also, Per project I went to look in .git/info/exclude. Also there no entries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. Eclipse generates a **hidden** .gitignore_global file in my default user home folder.

There are all kind of file extensions which are ignored, including .launch

Found it by going to Preferences > Team > Configuration > User Settings